# Syntax Error in Laravel - syntax error, unexpected token \"=\", expecting \"]\"

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to send a mail through Postman but it sends a 500 error response.

Here's the code in my controller:

```
Mail::to($user->email_address)->send(new ClientFinalRegistration($user));
```

It return an error response in Postman.

"error": "syntax error, unexpected token "=", expecting "]""

What does it mean?

---

**EDIT:**

Notice the **faqURL** key. I forgot to put "**>**" after the equals sign. That's where the problem occurs.

In my Mail/ClientFinalRegistration.php

```
/**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject($this->subject)
            ->markdown($this->view)
            ->with([
                'user' => $this->user,
                'faqURL' = $this->faqURL,
                'url' => $this->url,
            ]);
    }
```

Comment: Show your `.env`

Comment: env is not a problem because others are fine

Comment: Does Postman show the file and line of the error.

Comment: No it doesn't. But I know that it's that code causing the problem, because whenever I tried to remove it, it successfully continue to the next line

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? The code you've shared does not contain any `=` character

Comment: @NicoHaase I included the code to my question where the problem occurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is inside of the `ClientFinalRegistration` class. Probably when you were adding subject, body, etc.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. There's one missing character in my ClientFinalRegistration class. Arrow is missing. Instead of =>, I wrote there =.

Comment: No problem :D Happened too many times hahahah

Comment: Yep, I told this to my project manager too and he laughs as well and said "been there been there" lol